# What image formats are acceptable?

Tags: support, images, uploader

I want to upload a picture to one of my questions, but I keep trying different forms of the picture, but none of them work.

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

I have tried PNG and JPEG. What formats are acceptable?

Comment: What happens when you try uploading? (What do you mean by none of them work?)

Comment: It says, "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported"

Comment: images with http link are not supported.

Comment: What's the size of the image? There's a 2 mb limit.

Comment: @NogShine Thanks, I just needed to save the image instead of using the link

Comment: @Catija when the image is over 2 mb it shows a [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdlEE.jpg) that it's over 2 mb.

Comment: @WELZ it doesn't *always*... I had it giving me a generic error message the other day when trying to upload a GIF... making it smaller fixed the problem but it never told me that the size was bad.

Answer (score 4):

PNG, JPEG, GIF are all supported formats, your particular images were likely not encoded properly.

I would suggest trying to open them in MS Paint (or any other basic image editing software) and then saving it through there.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question of which image formats are acceptable.